# What are the pro and cons of vacuum sealed vs mylar bags for DIY dehydrated foods?

Tags: backpacking, food, diy

For packaging dehydrated foods for backpacking, the two options that I can think of are mylar bags and vacuum-sealed bags. What are the pros and cons of each method?

Comment: What are mylar bags?

Comment: @Alexander https://mylarpro.com/

Comment: Okay, thank you. Your question at least misses the storage time as an important parameter. For dehydrated food storage over some weeks, simple ziplock bags are an additional option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Mylar bags vs. Vacuum sealed.**

Pro.

- durability (in general, it depends; thickness is varying);
- you can pour inside boiled water without additional wares;
- more thermal isolation and great sun protection;
- can preserve wet and/or warm food;
- exists solutions for vacuuming, strong sealing, etc.;

Cons.

- slightly larger weight (thickness is varying; usually the packets weight is insignificant);
- more volume is consumed inside your backpack (if isn't vacuumed);
- non transparent, need signs, etc.;
- some air still closed inside (for some products in a long run, it may make a difference);
- can't be sealed by molding (most of time even a zip-lock will be ok);
- price (in general);

*Yes, I used both and had chosen the mylar bags. Maybe, I'm biased.*